# How to make sure fileInput needs action button input everytime the file is changed and not once

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to write a small app with shiny, this is my first, so I am no expert in programming. I want to upload a file with the fileInput function. The first time I click on browse and choose a file, I have to click on run before execution takes place, as intended! But when I choose another file, the program executes automatically and I have not to click on the run button again. I tried a lot but I dont know how to fix this, maybe it is obvious but I cant see it. To click again on run is essential for me as the function I use is huge. I simplified it inside this code with a simpler function but where my problem is the same: Data could be any dataframe saved as csv with "."as decimal e.g. `fr<-write.csv(data.frame(name=c(1:5),value=c(1:5)),**file**)`

```
    myfunction <- function(Data=matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2) ){
  if(all(Data==matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), nrow=3, ncol=2))==TRUE) return(list(name=data.frame(Notice=c("Hello, please load data")),name=data.frame(Notice=c("Hello, please load data")),name=data.frame(Notice=c("Hello, please load data"))))

  result=list(Data,Data,Data)
  return(result)
  }

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('
         #sidebar {
         background-color: #C3C2F3;

         }

         body, label, input, button, select { 
         font-family: "Arial";
         }')
  )),
  titlePanel("Hello"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(id="sidebar",
                 br(),
                 fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                           accept=c('text/csv', 
                                    'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                    '.csv')),
                 tags$hr(),
                 radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                              c(Comma=',',
                                Semicolon=';',
                                Tab='\t'),
                              ','),
                 selectInput("dataset", "Choose result:", 
                             choices = c("all matches in interval", "closest matches in interval","no matches")),
                 helpText("Note: save data with .csv"),
                 downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'),
                 actionButton("go","run",class = "btn-primary")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('mytable2')
    )
  )
    )



server <- function(input, output) {
  library(DT)
  library(magrittr)

  getData <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(input$file1))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, sep=input$sep,dec=".")


  })

  observeEvent(input$go,{
    result <- reactive({myfunction(getData())})


    datasetInput <- reactive({

      switch(input$dataset,
             "all matches in interval" = result()[[1]],
             "closest matches in interval" = result()[[2]],
             "no matches" = result()[[3]])

    })

    output$mytable2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      (DT::datatable(datasetInput(),rownames=FALSE) 
       %>% formatRound(c(1,2,3),digits=4))
    })


    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

      filename = function() { 
        paste(input$dataset,".csv", sep="")
      },

      content = function(file) {

        write.csv(datasetInput(), file)

      })})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

does anybody know how I manage it that after browse is used again for another file, I have to click on run again bevore execution takes place?

Many many thanks!!!

Comment: You might want to use a `submitButton`

Comment: thanks first, I tried it with submit in the first place but  when I select another choice: choices = c("all matches in interval", "closest matches in interval","no matches")), see code*. I have to click submit too and the program runs again the function for which it already had the results with the chosen inputfile just displying the second list element after recalculation, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isolate` to avoid a refresh when an input changes, and perform it when the actionButton is pressed, like in this small example:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui=fluidPage(textInput("NeedSubmit","NeedSubmit", value="a"), 
                      textInput("DontNeedSubmit","DontNeedSubmit", value="b"), 
                      actionButton("Submit","Submit"), 
                      textOutput("result")),
         server=function(input, output){
           observeEvent(input$Submit, {
                        output$result <- renderText(
                             paste(input$DontNeedSubmit, 
                                   isolate(input$NeedSubmit)))
                        })
         })
)
```